# ASP.NET Core Authorize & UserRoles in Multy Tenancy

Tags: asp.net-core, user-roles, authorize, asp.net-roles

We have am ASP.NET Core 6.0 multi tenant application with a single database. The tenant tables have a TenantId column to show only tenant data. We don't need to discuss whether is better or not to have multiple databases, for our purpose we need it this way.

All tenants share the users table and there is a UserTenant table to filter which users a tenant can see. But it is not relevant for this question.

We need to Authorize some controllers and for that we need to do this using roles:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "RoleA,RoleB,RoleC")]
public class SomeController : Controller
```

This way, a user can get into the controller only if belongs to one of those roles.

The problem is we need to assign roles to users in a certain tenant. So a "UserA" can have the "RoleA" in "TenantA", but not in "TenantB".

The Roles would be the same for all the tenants, so no tenantId in the table "aspnetroles", but we do need another property for table "aspnetuserroles" since the key sould be "UserId, RoleId,TenantId".

Our Application user is configured this way:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int>
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = String.Empty;
    public string Surname { get; set; } = String.Empty;
    public string? Alias { get; set; }
    ....
}

public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole<int> { }

public class ApplicationUserLogin : IdentityRole<int> { }
```

How can we change the Identity UserRoles in order to, not only store the UserId, RoleId and TenantId but also to work with the Authorize in the controller?

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE 1

I have been able to customize the aspnetuserroles table, the Client is our Tenant. This way we have already the table modified:

```
public class ApplicationUserRole : IdentityUserRole<int>
{
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    public Client Client { get; set; }

    public static void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        var e = modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUserRole>();

        e.HasKey(p => new { p.UserId, p.RoleId, p.ClientId });

        e.HasOne(p => p.Client).WithMany().HasForeignKey(tr => tr.ClientId).HasConstraintName("FK_UserRole_Client").IsRequired().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
    }
}
```

UPDATE 2

We have been able to modify the UserManager so we can add roles using the TenantId, in our case the ClientId.

```
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
{
    private readonly UserStore<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, DataContext, int, IdentityUserClaim<int>, ApplicationUserRole, IdentityUserLogin<int>, IdentityUserToken<int>, IdentityRoleClaim<int>> _store;

    public ApplicationUserManager(
        IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store,
        IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor,
        IPasswordHasher<ApplicationUser> passwordHasher,
        IEnumerable<IUserValidator<ApplicationUser>> userValidators,
        IEnumerable<IPasswordValidator<ApplicationUser>> passwordValidators,
        ILookupNormalizer keyNormalizer,
        IdentityErrorDescriber errors,
        IServiceProvider services,
        ILogger<UserManager<ApplicationUser>> logger)
        : base(store, optionsAccessor, passwordHasher, userValidators, passwordValidators, keyNormalizer, errors, services, logger)
    {
        _store = (UserStore<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, DataContext, int, IdentityUserClaim<int>, ApplicationUserRole, IdentityUserLogin<int>, IdentityUserToken<int>, IdentityRoleClaim<int>>)store;
    }


    public virtual async Task<IdentityResult> AddToRoleByClientAsync(ApplicationUser user, string role, int clientId)
    {
        ThrowIfDisposed();

        if (user == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(user));

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(role))
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(role));

        if (clientId == 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(clientId));

        var normalizedRole = NormalizeName(role);

        var applicationRole = _store.Context.Roles.FirstOrDefault(p => p.NormalizedName == normalizedRole);
        if (applicationRole == null)
            return IdentityResult.Failed(ErrorDescriber.InvalidRoleName(normalizedRole));

        if (await IsInRoleByRoleIdClientAsync(user, applicationRole.Id, clientId))
            return IdentityResult.Failed(ErrorDescriber.UserAlreadyInRole(normalizedRole));

        _store.Context.Set<ApplicationUserRole>().Add(new ApplicationUserRole { RoleId = applicationRole.Id, UserId = user.Id, ClientId = clientId });

        return await UpdateUserAsync(user);
    }

    private async Task<bool> IsInRoleByRoleIdClientAsync(ApplicationUser user, int roleId, int clientId, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        ThrowIfDisposed();

        if (user == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(user));

        if (roleId == 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(roleId));

        if (clientId == 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(clientId));

        var userRole = await _store.Context.Set<ApplicationUserRole>().FindAsync(new object[] { user.Id, roleId, clientId }, cancellationToken);
        return userRole != null;
    }

    public async Task<bool> IsInRoleByClientAsync(ApplicationUser user, string role, int clientId)
    {
        ThrowIfDisposed();

        if (user == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(user));

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(role))
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(role));

        if (clientId == 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(clientId));

        var normalizedRole = NormalizeName(role);

        var applicationRole = _store.Context.Roles.FirstOrDefault(p => p.NormalizedName == normalizedRole);
        if (applicationRole == null)
            return false;

        var userRole = await _store.Context.Set<ApplicationUserRole>().FindAsync(new object[] { user.Id, applicationRole.Id, clientId });
        return userRole != null;
    }
}
```

We still need to modify the [Authorize(Roles = "admin")] in order to check the roles of the current Tenant and not all of them. We are investigating this.

Comment: As an idea, with all the conclusions you have,  why don't you use a Custom Authorize Attribute to check whether a user has that role in the tenant but doesn't have in another one.  In that attribute, you can use UserManager to do whatever you want. If I have given you a wrong solution, please inform me about it so that we can discuss :)

Comment: I'm afraid the role-based authorization can't meet your requirement since different tenants may have the same role, and role-based auth can only set role name in the attribute, so I'm afraid you need to use policy based auth. For example, if you are having a frontend-backend structure, in your client app you can generate access token containing tenant/role information, then in the backend api, write custom jwt auth policy to do the authorization.

Comment: If you had a MVC application, then you need to write implement of `IAuthorizationHandler` like this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/secure-data?view=aspnetcore-7.0#register-the-authorization-handlers) then you can custom  the auth logic to realize your requirement.

Comment: AFter a lot of research, I think loading the rights for the user at login in claims and using a claims policy based in the AUthorize would be the best solution. I can store in a 
 table UserClientRoles the corresponding roles for each client(tenant).